# SharpDX sees the PS4 gamepad as a joystick, not a controller

Tags: c#, controller, sharpdx

I have a problem with SharpDX. It see my PS4 controller as a joystick, not as a controller. As a result, I don't have access to some functions, e.g. vibration.
This code works fine (as joystick):

```cs
foreach (var selectControler in input.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl,DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        _joystick = new Joystick(input, selectControler.InstanceGuid);
        _joystick.Acquire();
        _timer = new Timer(x => Update());
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but this one detects no controller:

```cs
for (UserIndex i = UserIndex.One; i <= UserIndex.Four; i++)
{
    _controller =new Controller(i);
    if (_controller.IsConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scan Input {0} for gamepad - {1}", i, _controller.GetCapabilities(DeviceQueryType.Gamepad).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        _timer = new Timer(x => Update());

        break;
    }
    else _controller = null;
}
```

Steam and other applications normally detect this controller. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You need to install a driver to make it work as xInput, something like [ScpToolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scptoolkit.mirror/)